# Using amplify to integrate app into existing AWS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-amplify

I'm developing an Android app that needs to work with an existing Amazon Web Service RDS database as well as an S3 bucket server also on AWS. My issue is that I'm struggling to find much in the way on guidance on the best approach to do so.

Currently the best thing I've found is Amazon's Amplify, the alternatives so far being SQLiteOpenHelper (seemingly unideal given that it looks to work almost exclusively with local databases, but an interesting caching option) and using Apache, which seems bad as it is extremely manual and largely deprecated.

Am I correct in then concluding Amplify is the best direction to take, or am I missing something big (it feels this way), in which case advice on how better to research this task would be **immensely** appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amplify allows you to connect your app with any kind of datasource using AppSync, which is a GraphQL service managed, via resolvers that connects to anything that you want.

AppSync provides a GraphQL API including features like request and response mapping, authentication, cache and other useful things. Here you can have an overview about how it works https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-microservices/.

About how to use S3, Amplify can help with it, using amplify/cli is easy to add that resource, just running `amplify add storage`, as explained here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/android/.