# How to connect AWS Amplify project to existing AWS RDS database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-amplify, continuous-deployment

I am very new to AWS services, and have deployed an existing reactjs project in AWS Amplify. I also have an existing AWS RDS instance that hosts my database / data source. The reactjs project was not developed using the AWS Amplify CLI. The deployed project has its own NodeJS API calls that is used to retrieve and update data, however it does not connect to my postgresql DB in RDS. How can I connect the Amplify project to the RDS database? Do I need other (several) AWS services to do so?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458665/using-amplify-to-integrate-app-into-existing-aws-database

Comment: There is this, but I am not sure how much it will help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/connect-amplify-datastore-with-existing-sql-datasources-adding-offline-and-sync-features-in-your-application/